# How to link a library installed by vcpkg using CMake?

Tags: cmake, vcpkg, cmake-gui

I installed a third party library using vcpkg.
If I write full path to library in include_directories and etc. commands it works but this is silly. I'm trying to include this library using proper approach but CMake returns an error.

I tried advices from similar questions but thus far I was unable to solve the problem

This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
SET(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "$ENV{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")

project(ESMTOOLKIT)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.5)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ../bin)

find_package(LibXml2 REQUIRED)

#include_directories(C:/Users/user/source/vcpkg/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include include)
include_directories(${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIRS} include)
#link_directories(C:/Users/user/source/vcpkg/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib)

set(SOURCES xmlUtils.cpp include/xmlUtils.h pch.cpp include/pch.h esmReader.cpp)

add_executable(esmToolkit ${SOURCES})

#target_link_libraries(esmToolkit libxml2.lib)
target_link_libraries(esmToolkit PRIVATE ${LIBXML2_LIBRARIES})

add_subdirectory(subrecords)
add_subdirectory(records)
```

This is the error message that I get:

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/3_24/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find LibXml2 (missing: LIBXML2_LIBRARY LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/3_24/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/3_24/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindLibXml2.cmake:108 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/user/source/repos/esmToolkit/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I have the following environmental variables set:

```
VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET x64-windows
VCPKG_ROOT C:\Users\user\source\vcpkg\vcpkg
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Normally, `cmake_minimum_required` should come at the very **first line** of `CMakeLists.txt`. Placing it after the `project()` call could give weird effects. Doesn't CMake warn you about missed `cmake_minimum_required` in your code?

Comment: Nope. No warnings. I did used Cmake GUI though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fixed an issue though I'm not sure what in particular fixed it.

First, I found that I have path to CMake missing from Path environmental variable (C:\Program Files\CMake\3_24\bin).

Second, I removed link_directories command and replaced include_directories command with a target_include_directories.

Third, I changed how I use target_link_libraries command. The correct way for my case is the following: `target_link_libraries(esmToolkit PRIVATE LibXml2::LibXml2)`

Now CMake generates correct solution from both command line and CMake-GUI

Comment: It's generally good practice to include the full content of your working CMakeLists.txt in your answer so others have an easier time understanding and replicating your solution.

Answer (score 0):

[`CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE.html) may not be specfied in CMakeLists.txt:

> This variable is specified **on the command line** when cross-compiling with CMake.

Therefore you must run it in PowerShell

```bash
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "$ENV{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"`
```

or in the developer command prompt

```bash
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "%VCPKG_ROOT%/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"`
```

Ensure you define `VCPKG_ROOT` environment variable properly, or use the actual full path to `vcpkg.cmake`, see the guide [Get started with vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html).

Note, `cmake_minimum_required()` should be on the top line of CMakeLists.txt, `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` should be located prior the `project()` directive.

vcpkg's `find_package()` can be case-sensive, it's better to use the official name `libxml2`.

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.5)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

project(ESMTOOLKIT)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ../bin)

find_package(libxml2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIRS} include)

set(SOURCES xmlUtils.cpp include/xmlUtils.h pch.cpp include/pch.h esmReader.cpp)

add_executable(esmToolkit ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(esmToolkit PRIVATE LibXml2::LibXml2)
```

For example I run

```bash
git clone git@github.com:microsoft/vcpkg.git C:/Work/3rd/vcpkg
```

and this works well for me

```bash
cmake -S . -B build -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Work/3rd/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

Comment: While it is *preferrable* to specify `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` variable in the command line, it is perfectly **acceptable** to specify it in the `CMakeLists.txt` before the first `project()` call.

Comment: I just noted that your first statement - "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE may not be specfied in CMakeLists.txt" is not true. And the manual doesn't confirm this statement. (BTW, a vcpkg toolchain doesn't imply **cross-compiling**, it just adjusts come paths which point to the installed libraries and packages).

Comment: I specfied CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE in CMakeLists.txt in order to be able to configure project via Cmake GUI.
VCPKG_ROOT is define properly and anyway changing this line to full path without enviromental variable does not make it work.
If I path "libxml2" to find_package than CMake returns the following error: "
The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (LibXml2)
  does not match the name of the calling package (libxml2) "
- thus I assumed that this is wrong